# GNU make lint prerequisite

Tags: makefile, lint, eslint

The [GNU `make` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) says:

> A phony target should not be a prerequisite of a real target file; if it is, its recipe will be run every time `make` goes to update that file.

What if that's what I want?

For example, what if I have a phony target called `lint` that lints `app/scripts/main.js`, and I want it to run every time `make` goes to update (transpile & minify) `dist/scripts/main.js`?

Comment: Note: I know about Gulp and prefer to use Make.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the `lint` target and put its recipe as the first command of the recipe for the `dist/scripts/main.js` target.

```
dist/scripts/main.js : app/scripts/main.js
    ./node_modules/.bin/eslint $< && \
    mkdir -p dist/scripts && \
    ./node_modules/.bin/babel $< | \
    ./node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs - --screw-ie8 -o $@ -m -c
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer: the current GNU make manual does not specify the cited "rule" from the question but instead explicit says to make use of this in the entry about [forced targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Force-Targets), which includes a note:

> As you can see, using `FORCE` this way has the same results as using `.PHONY clean`.
>
> Using `.PHONY` is more explicit and more efficient. However, other versions of make do not support `.PHONY`; thus `FORCE` appears in many makefiles